# how to get the current gps coordinates in xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, cllocationmanager

I would like to get the user's current latitude and longitude for ios in xamarin.

I've looked at other posts and as i understand it.

it's like:

```
CLLocationManager lm = new CLLocationManager();
... (Acurray)
... (Other Specs)
lm.StartUpdatingLocation();
lm.Location.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString();
lm.Location.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString();
```

However, when i run it in the simulator it doesn't do anything. It doesn't ask me to turn on my location services or update my Label with the latitude and longitude.

Also, how do i make it check it location services are turned on and if they're not. How to make the user do it. (like the pop up on some apps asking you to turn on your gps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CLLocationManger is async - it will fire events when the location is updated.

```
CLLocationManager lm = new CLLocationManager(); //changed the class name
... (Acurray)
... (Other Specs)

lm.LocationsUpdated += delegate(object sender, CLLocationsUpdatedEventArgs e) {
    foreach(CLLocation l in e.Locations) {
        Console.WriteLine(l.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString() + ", " +l.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString());
    }
};

lm.StartUpdatingLocation();
```

Comment: Do you how to get the location name from the latitude and longitude?

Comment: Use Reverse Geocoding - http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/geocoder/reverse_geocode_a_location/

Comment: @Jason this still works? What is the namespace for CLLocationManager ?? and what are those `(....)` ?? trying to get coordinates but just starting with Xamarin so kind of lost.