# Xamarin.iOS geolocation

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have been browsing the web for a couple of hours to find ways to get the device's geolocation but to no avail.

I could find some documentation for android, but nothing for iOS. Anyone has any ideas or can point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Xamarin.Mobile](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.mobile) component has a cross-platform GeoLocation service.  It comes with samples.

Xamarin also has a [Core Location sample app](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/CoreLocation/).

This question has also been asked and answered on Stack Overflow [many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015791/how-to-get-the-current-gps-coordinates-in-xamarin).

```
CLLocationManger lm = new CLLocationManger();
... (Acurray)
... (Other Specs)

lm.LocationsUpdated += delegate(object sender, CLLocationsUpdatedEventArgs e) {
    foreach(CLLocation l in e.Locations) {
        Console.WriteLine(l.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString() + ", " +l.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString());
    }
};

lm.StartUpdatingLocation();
```

Comment: I searched for Xamarin geolocation several times for hours. I wouldn't have asked the question without research. This is exactly what I need though, thank you very much.

Comment: I just want to let you know that I love you man. I'm honestly learning more from your answers than the Xamarin webpage itself!