# Get user's current location in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, cllocationmanager

I would like to get the user's current location in iOS Xamarin. Here is my code.

```
CLLocationManager locationManager = new CLLocationManager();
locationManager.StartUpdatingLocation();
locationManager.StartUpdatingHeading();

locationManager.LocationsUpdated += delegate(object sender , CLLocationsUpdatedEventArgs e )
{
    foreach(CLLocation loc in e.Locations)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(loc.Coordinate.Latitude);
    }
};
```

1.When i launch my app, a dialog "AppName would like to use your current location" pops in and after one or two seconds it dismisses by itself(before i could click any button). Why is this happening?

2.
 App works fine when i manually(settings->privacy->locations) enable location services for my app. I want this to happen programmatically. I have checked [this post](https://github.com/in-the-keyhole/khs-blog-examples) also similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015791/how-to-get-the-current-gps-coordinates-in-xamarin).Where am i going wrong?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Is this for iOS8? Did you call RequestWhenInUseAuthorization?

As for the dismiss of the dialog, that is most likely due to the locationManager variable not being declared at the class level.

Comment: Thank you for your response.This is not for iOS8 and moving locationManager to class level did not do the trick.Dialog box dismisses only on iOS7, works fine on iOS6!! strange!